# Drawing graphs in PHP

Tags: php, dynamic, graph

I am using PHP to generate graphs from arrays. I wish to create multiple graphs on the same page as I need to design a summary report from answers extracted from a database.
Currently I am using this code and am only able to get one single graph. What additions to the code do I need to make to get multiple graphs?

```
<?php
    function draw_graph($values)
    {
        // Get the total number of columns we are going to plot
        $columns  = count($values);

        // Get the height and width of the final image
        $width = 300;
        $height = 200;

        // Set the amount of space between each column
        $padding = 5;

        // Get the width of 1 column
        $column_width = $width / $columns ;

        // Generate the image variables

        $im        = imagecreate($width,$height);
        $gray      = imagecolorallocate ($im,0xcc,0xcc,0xcc);
        $gray_lite = imagecolorallocate ($im,0xee,0xee,0xee);
        $gray_dark = imagecolorallocate ($im,0x7f,0x7f,0x7f);
        $white     = imagecolorallocate ($im,0xff,0xff,0xff);

        // Fill in the background of the image
        imagefilledrectangle($im,0,0,$width,$height,$white);
        $maxv = 0;

        // Calculate the maximum value we are going to plot
        for($i=0;$i<$columns;$i++)$maxv = max($values[$i],$maxv);

        // Now plot each column
        for($i=0;$i<$columns;$i++)
        {
            $column_height = ($height / 100) * (( $values[$i] / $maxv) *100);
            $x1 = $i*$column_width;
            $y1 = $height-$column_height;
            $x2 = (($i+1)*$column_width)-$padding;
            $y2 = $height;
            imagefilledrectangle($im,$x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$gray_dark);
        }

        header ("Content-type: image/png");
        imagepng($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }

    $values = array("23","32","35","57","12");
    $values2 = array("123","232","335","157","102");
    draw_graph($values2);
    draw_graph($values);//no output is coming
    draw_graph($values2);//no output is coming
    draw_graph($values);//no output is coming
?>
```

Comment: thanks for fixing the code. pretty code = easier to read

Answer (score 3):

I'm no GD expert, so I prefer to use the [Google Chart Tools API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/). It saves a lot of PHP graph making nightmares and has a nice set of features for providing, formatting, and styling data.

If you want to stick to your code that's OK too. I'll start with the obvious: is GD enabled? If it is, then your problem is trying to export multiple images on one page. Remove all but one of the calls to draw_graph and see what kind of output you get.

```
<?php
function combine_graphs( $graph_values ) {
    $Yoffset = 0;
    $image = imagecreate( 300, 200 * count( $graph_values ) );

    foreach( $graph_values as $values ) {
        draw_graph( $values, $image, $Yoffset ); //Be sure to add y offsets and not call imagepng() in here
        $Yoffset += 200;
    }

    //Let the master function output the image
    header ("Content-type: image/png");    
    imagepng($im);  
    imagedestroy($im);
}

//Usage
combine_graphs( array( $dataForGraph1, $dataForGraph2, $dataForGraph3 ) );
?>
```

Comment: i am getting a single output... but what i need is multiple outputs... the first drawgraph is giginv me an output...

Comment: you'll have to do a little reworking to your function then...I suggest creating a master function that calls `draw_graph` and passes a GD instance to write to and a Y offset that will ensure none of the graphs overlap...

Comment: also another problem i have is that this php code will be running on a local server which doesnt have access to the internet so i cannot use google apis

Answer (score 2):

Your output is made with `header` so you cant output twice (no header after output is allowed).
You should take a look as some plotting utility ([Google charts](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/chart/) for example), or use a php script for draw request parameter ($_GET for exemple) and then use `graph.php?data=...` in your UI page.

Comment: actually multiple headers are allowed just fine, but not after another output was sent out.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't outputting a HTML page with multiple images, but rather an image file (you change the content-type header to image/png) so you can only output one image this way since you can't send headers again once you've already sent output (which is what `imagepng()` does).

What you want to do is to create another page which will have the multiple images, and use the page with the above function as the image src. You should then just pass in the graph parameters (or store them in a session or database, however you want) and use that information to create the image.

So if your above code was in a file called "make_graph.php", you would create a different HTML file with the following, and adjust your current code to take it's values from $_GET.

```
<img src="make_graph.php?values=23;32;35;57;12" />
<img src="make_graph.php?values=123;232;335;157;102" />
```

Then what I've called "make_graph.php" would be,

```
<?php
function draw_graph($values)
{
    // ... your current code
}

$values = explode(";", $_GET['values']); // You'll probably want to sanitize $_GET input
make_graph($values);
?>
```

The other thing you could try would be to merge all the images into one big image. So you create a final image which has the same width but the height is that of all 4 images combined, and the final image is that of all 4 graphs on top of one another (I don't mean layered, I mean the second graph appears below the 1st, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you need four graphs, you would have either to do four image tags, each of which refers to a separate image, or one big image that contains the images one after another (i.e. one starts at 0, second at `$height`, etc. and the whole image would have size `$height*4`. You can't just output one image after  another, it doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 0):

In your code only one picture at the time !
and instead reinventing the wheel I suggest to use library - I recommend pChart